# empty space after all elements in groupedlistview Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using the groupedlistview library and I have a problem, after all the elements there is an empty space, how to get rid of it?

```
GroupedListView<BookComposition, String>(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              elements: _elements,
                              groupBy: (element) => element.ticketTypeName!,
                              groupComparator: (value1, value2) => value2.compareTo(value1),
                              itemComparator: (item1, item2) =>                                 item1.ticketTypeName!.compareTo(item2.ticketTypeName!),
                              order: GroupedListOrder.ASC,
                              useStickyGroupSeparators: false,
                              groupSeparatorBuilder: (String typeName) =>
                                  Container(
                                    height: 0,
                                  ),
                              itemBuilder: (c, element) {
                                if (element.ticketTypeName == ticketTypeName) {
                                  return ActionsTile(...);
                                }
                                return Container();
                              }),
```

I don’t seem to have any indentations, but the problem persists. help me please

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
```

add padding on GroupedListView

```
        GroupedListView<BookComposition, String>(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          elements: _elements,
          groupBy: (element) => element.ticketTypeName!,
          groupComparator: (value1, value2) => value2.compareTo(value1),
          itemComparator: (item1, item2) => item1.ticketTypeName!.compareTo(item2.ticketTypeName!),
          order: GroupedListOrder.ASC,
          useStickyGroupSeparators: false,
          groupSeparatorBuilder: (String typeName) =>
              Container(
                height: 0,
              ),
          itemBuilder: (c, element) {
            if (element.ticketTypeName == ticketTypeName) {
              return ActionsTile(...);
            }
            return Container();
          },),
```